# jquery to merge table second column value to next column values

Tags: jquery

I want to merge the column 2 values with column 3 in my table, and my table having more than 20 row.

I am adding class for column 2 for class="column2" and 3 for class="column3".
and my table class name is genTable.

How to merge each column 2 values in to column 3..eg. in column2 i have 'firstname' and column 3 i have 'lastname' as test then after this script i want to see as 'firstname lastname' together incolumn 3 for all the columns ?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(".genTable tr").each(function(){
            var col2value = $(".column2").text();
            var col3value = $(".column3").text();
            $(col2value).append(col3value);
     })
});
```

how to merge each column values in to another for all rows? do we need to use for loop ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z8k1efk6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append `column3` contents to `column2` and after that remove `column3` from the table:

```
$(".genTable tr .column2").append(function() {
    return ' ' + $(this).next('.column3').remove().html();
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
$(".genTable tr .column2").append(function() {
    return ' ' + $(this).next().remove().html();
});
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
table td, table th {padding: 10px 5px; border: 1px #AAA solid;}
table th {background: #EEE;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="genTable">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th class="column2">First name</th>
        <th class="column3">Last name</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="column2">Thomas</td>
        <td class="column3">Mann</td>
        <td>Writer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="column2">Jon</td>
        <td class="column3">Smith</td>
        <td>Artist</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solutions. but where i need to call the "public class User" and how its refer inside the $(".genTable tr .column2")? am i want to call "public class User" this inside my ready? or separate script ? how to manipulate using only dom? rather than defining public... because i am implmenting the same in my jqgrid...

Comment: Hm.. What "public class User" are you talking about?

Comment: In you code: $(".genTable tr .column2").append(function() {
    return ' ' + $(this).next('.column3').remove().html();
}); how it merge the two values ?

Comment: What it does is, it iterates over every `.column2` and appends contents of the next adjacent `.column3`, then every current `.column3` is removed.

Comment: ok, but if i have empty cell it showing as "null" text in the column... how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Option 1 :** Use jquery **closest()** or **next()** function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".genTable tr td.column2").each(function(){
          var col2value = $(this).text();// replace text() with html() to get/set entire html inside selected html element
          var col3value =  $(this).next("td.column3").text(); 
          $(this).text(col2value + " " +  col3value);
       });
});
```

[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/ahnr263u/)...

**2. Option 2 :** Add one more property to your class ( say your class name is User )

```
public class User
   {
      public string FirstName {get; set;}
      public string LastName {get; set;}
      public string FullName {get {return FirstName + LastName ;}}
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, you have any idea about if i have empty cell (col3value) it consider "null" as text in respective column2. how to avoid that ? –

Comment: Thanks for your updates. now we are coordinating the values as text right, instead can we able move the whole html construct to the next column, because i may have not only text value also possible for anchor element or some click event on that also!! in that case how can we handle this ?

Comment: yes we can, just replace text() with html(), for reference https://jsfiddle.net/0n8fvj9t/